# Optional chaining and Array in swift

Tags: swift

Let's take these two simple classes to show my problem:

```
class Object{  
    var name:String?
    // keep it simple... and useless
}

class TestClass {
    var objects:AnyObject[]? 

    func initializeObjects (){
        objects?.insert(Object(), atIndex:0) // Error
        objects?.insert(Object(), atIndex:1) // Error
        objects?.insert(Object(), atIndex:2) // Error
    }
}
```

With this implementation I get 3 errors `Could not find member 'insert'` where I try to add object into the `objects` array.

Now, if I remove the optional from `objects` definition and the optional chain in `initializeObjects` it works with no problem (here the working code)

```
class Object{
    var name:String?
}

class TestClass {
    var objects:AnyObject[] = AnyObject[]() // REMOVE optional and initialize an empty array

    func initializeObjects (){
        objects.insert(Object(), atIndex:0) // Remove Opt chaining 
        objects.insert(Object(), atIndex:1) // Remove Opt chaining
        objects.insert(Object(), atIndex:2) // Remove Opt chaining
    }
}
```

I can't understand what is wrong in the first implementation. 
I thought it checks with `objects?` if `objects` is not `nil` and at this point it adds an element using `insert:atIndex:`. But I'm probably wrong -.-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays in Swift are structs and structs are value types.
Optionals in Swift are actually enums (`Optional<T>` or `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<T>`).

When you are unwrapping an optional (implicitly or explicitly) of a value type, what you get is actually a constant copy of the struct. And you can't call `mutating` methods on a constant struct.

Executing `objects?.insert(Object(), atIndex:0)` basically means this:

```
if let tmp = objects {
    tmp.insert(Object(), atIndex:0)
}
```

As a workaround, you need to assign the unwrapped value to a variable and then assign the variable back to your optional property. That's how value types work.

This is reproducible for any struct, not only Arrays:

```
struct S {
    var value: Int = 0
}

var varS: S = S()
varS.value = 10 //can be called

let constS: S = S()
constS.value = 10 //cannot be called - constant!

var optionalS: S? = S()
optionalS?.value = 10 //cannot be called, unwrapping makes a constant copy!

//workaround
if optionalS {
    var tmpS = optionalS!
    tmpS.value = 10
    optionalS = tmpS
}
```

Some relevant discussion here: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/233111?tstart=60

Comment: Could we say that initializing an Array in a class is a sort of good practice to avoid the workaround? (btw, great answer!)

Comment: @MatterGoal Or `NSArray`? There was a discussion about this on Apple Dev forums recently. There also seems to be a bug when you call `array?[index] = something` which compiles but doesn't do anything.

Comment: Where did you get this "When you are unwrapping an optional (implicitly or explicitly) of a value type, what you get is actually a constant copy of the struct" I can't find that in the guide! It is really important info.

Comment: @MatterGoal It is important and undocumented. It comes from the fact that optionals are implemented using an `enum`. It's not just syntactic sugar. Even the enum has to make a copy of a value type when returning. And the constantness of the return value is because it's a temporary variable - if you don't assign it to something, you can't change it because the change would be lost.

Comment: @Sulthan, shouldn't the line `optionalS?.value = 10` by `optionalS!.value = 10`