# Are optional arrays designed to be "immutable"?

Tags: ios, swift

As i found in documentation, arrays declared by var are mutable by default

```
var A: Int[] = [1,2,3]
A += 4
A //[1,2,3,4]
```

But i never found reason, why are optional arrays immutable (should they be and why). These two examples illustates my concern:

```
var A: Int[]? = [1,2,3]
A! += 4 // Error: could not find operator += etc. - .append does not work as well
A
```

this gives error, but this one does not

```
var A: Int[]? = [1,2,3]
var B = A!
B += 4
A = B
A  // [1,2,3,4]
```

and performs as expected. Is there any particular reason, why it cannot be done in one line, like in previous example? As far as i see from that, underlaying array is like constructed by let, but it does not makes sense to me yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optional chaining and Array in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451960/optional-chaining-and-array-in-swift)

Comment: This is actually valid for any value type, not just arrays.

Comment: this is basically what i thought, but is it meant to be that way? Or is it something i could hope to be improved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your var A is of type Int[]? whilst your var B is *not* - it is implicitly of type Int[], since you set it equal to the unwrapped value of A.

B can therefore be appended to (it's a var array), whilst A cannot be (it's a var, but not an array - it's an optional wrapping an array), but, as A is Int[]? you can assign the modified B to it. To append to an optional array you would have to "unwrap" it as an LHS like

```
A! += 4 // Doesn't work
```

Comment: yes - i should unwrap it - but for now, it seems that there is no way to wrap a mutable array - all arrays wrapped as optionals are immutable, and that's what concerns me